Is it correct to say that DepthFirst Search has the space complexity O(bm) and DepthFirst IterativeDeepening O(d)?
Is it correct to state that the space complexity of Depth-First Search (DFS) is $O(bm)$ and that of Iterative Deepening Depth-First Search (IDDFS) is $O(d)$?
Here, $b$ represents the branching factor, $m$ the maximum depth, and $d$ the depth reached by iterative deepening. If I provide definitions for these two algorithms, can I then accurately apply these complexity measures?

@greybeard I don't think space complexity and number of operations are equal.
